# How to create Namespace and Set

Tags: database, aerospike, aerospike-ce, aerospike-loader

I'm new to Aerospike..
How to create a New Namespace and new set..
I have gone thru some docs and videos but I didn't find any useful thing.
i have read somewhere which is 5 years old blog, i.e. thru config file only we can create namespace and set.
is that true or any other commands are there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to create a `namespace` you'll need to modify the `aerospike.conf` file since `namespaces` cannot be created dynamically.
By default the "test" `namespace` is included in the `aerospike.conf` file (located in `/etc/aerospike/aerospike.conf`).

You can read more about [Aerospike configuration](https://docs.aerospike.com/reference/configuration) and [Namespace configuration](https://docs.aerospike.com/server/operations/configure/namespace).

`Sets` can be "created" dynamically (it is a logical hierarchy) so you don't have to "create" `sets` you can just specify the `set` you want to write/update/delete/read from in the operation.

If you are new to `Aerospike` I suggest to use the [Interactive Tutorials](https://developer.aerospike.com/tutorials) (currently available for `Java`, `Python` and `Spark`) or the [Client Libraries](https://developer.aerospike.com/client) documentation to see some code examples.